# Oracle JDBC Driver with Java 9 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-9

I'm trying to get a Java application working with Java 9+. When running in the 1.9 jre, I get the following stack trace:

```
2018-06-06 11:22:54.304 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
2018-06-06 11:22:54.305 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr) 

2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr)    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr) 

2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr)    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr) 

2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr)    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(Unknown Source)
2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr) 

2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr)    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(Unknown Source)
2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr) 

2018-06-06 11:22:54.306 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr)    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(Unknown Source)
2018-06-06 11:22:54.307 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr) 

2018-06-06 11:22:54.307 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr)    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(Unknown Source)
2018-06-06 11:22:54.307 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr) 

2018-06-06 11:22:54.307 ERROR - main - Replicator - (stderr)    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.<clinit>(BasicDataSource.java:77)
```

I have confirmed that the classpath is accurate because 1. this runs fine in Java 8, and 2. all other .jars are properly loaded when running in 9. Has anyone had any luck running Oracle jdbc drivers on Java 9+?

Comment: `Could not initialize class XYZ` indicates that the JVM has already tried and failed to load class `XYZ`.  There must have been a previous failed attempt to initialize this class which generated a different error.  I'm guessing this is a web app: if so, and you restart your web app container and try again do you get a different error message the first time?  Also, which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver is this?

Comment: Oracle JDBC 12.2 works fine with JDK9.

Comment: I am using 12.2 so it must be something else. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem ended up showing itself once I turned on trace logging for DriverManager. An old jconn driver for Sybase was conflicting with Java 9/10 and causing the DriverManager to error out. Seeing as it is now a deprecated driver it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to re-order(put oracle dependency prior/much prior to all sybase) sybase and ojdbc8 jar dependency in pom.xml. it worked for me.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
            <version>7.07-27082</version>
        </dependency>
```